# Cannot find the Create GUID tool in VS2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, guid, create-guid

I have Visual Studio 2005 Professional ENU installed and want to create GUIDs using its Create GUIDs utility. However, I cannot find it under the Tools menu. What should I do to get this utility? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<visual studio install>\Common7\Tools\guidgen.exe

Answer (score 3):

I find it handy to use a GUID generator macro than using the GUID generator. You can assign a shortcut key combination for this macro and insert new GUIDs instantly anywhere in the code.

Here is the code for the interested:

```
Public Module GUIDGenModule

    Sub Create_GUID()
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D").ToUpper()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

File path and name below
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\guidgen.exe

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\guidgen.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\uuidgen.exe
```

The first one is the GUI tool. The second one is a handy console line tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it wouldn't be on your Tools menu, but the file you're looking for is called guidgen.exe, and it should be in the Tools folder, i.e. \Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\guidge.exe.

Another thing you could try is to reset your IDE settings.  Select "Tools --> Import and Export Settings --> Reset All Settings" to restore the defaults and see if that restores the GUID option to the Tools menu.  If you've customized a lot of your settings, you might actually export them first so that you can roll back once you figure out the GUID issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually switched over to using PowerShell for a lot of tasks that used to be done through spawned tools... try this:

```
[guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I've blogged about some handy Visual Studio macro's that generate new GUIDs. You can bind those macro's to your keyboard and generate GUIDs on the fly in the source editor. Read about them here:

http://www.wirwar.com/blog/2007/11/03/generating-guids-in-the-visual-studio-ide/

Answer (score 0):

The facter of the proble is product package selection.
The tool is C++ addons.
So when you have vs pro above(not only c#...), install c++ part.

Answer (score -2):

```
9a005ff3-5dee-4667-b5b9-7663fee2b0f9
db031ebf-7ffa-4604-a6b6-7d60a38c60ca
96f1854c-3654-46a7-8f57-20eb23f62375
f43a4642-db72-4ed5-a9e7-32fc2c53d1f1
6fa5c074-d68c-4871-b26f-1e0b51374865
17cf6675-fce6-42ce-8501-f19dadbe0c6d
65c681ad-701e-4bc6-a373-2351d9fc1910
3eab6e3d-4040-4beb-9c79-57a0bd7c84c9
3aae1801-c595-4f0b-a36c-56f41e5858dd
310f9053-319e-457c-aedf-ba9a1cd6a1cb
```

Here are ten free guids, but for only $19.95, I can send you the missing portion to my amazing Guid Generator:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine([GET THE WHOLE SOURCE! ONLY $19.99!]);
    }
```

Comment: would you just sell me 20 more guid's for 10$ because i only need 30 and dont need the source

Comment: Sure, but as insurance until I recieve my payment, I will not give you the 15th character.

I'm guessing nobody will get that :)

Comment: Would it be OK if I used these GUIDs, too?